# how to enable php7 module with ubuntu16.04

Tags: php, pdo, informix

I'm using ubuntu 16.04. I installed php7 with

```
apt-get install php
apt-get install php-cli
apt-get install php-dev
```

and installed apache2 with

```
apt-get install apache2
```

Now I want to use add a module pdo_informix, I already get the pdo_informix.so
and place it at

```
/usr/lib/php/20151012
```

then I use the following commands to active this module

```
cd /etc/php/7.0/mods-available
sudo su
touch pdo_informix.ini
```

and input the following in pdo_informix.ini

```
extension=pdo_informix.so
```

enable this config by

```
phpenmod pdo_informix
```

restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

then I want to check if the informix driver is correctly installed by running phpinfo(), I can't found the Informix PDO.
The pdo_informix.ini is correctly loaded as you may see:
[phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSVYc.png)

Am I doing something wrong?

Can someone help me

Comment: The pdo_informix is not yet compatible with php 7